# Unity3d Application.OpenURL on a mobile device(both Android and iOS)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this method that is used on several buttons.

```
public void OpenURL(string url)
{
  Application.OpenURL(url);
}
```

It is used to open several links for the social media of the game. Twitter, facebook and instagram links open just fine. How ever when provided with the link for our website The mobile device says "Cant open pdf ("address of website"). The website itself is still "under construction" and just has a background image(defined in the css) and a Coming soon text. Why is it trying to open a pdf and how do I fix this.

P.S When testing the button in the editor it works fine and opens up a new tab on the default browser.

Comment: What's the form of the URL you're passing ?

Try to format you're URL like this : `http://<YOUR_ADRESS_HERE>`
I've issued the same problem once.

Comment: Which mobile device? Android or iOS? It would also be good if you show what type of url you are passing to it.

Comment: I'll just copy/paste the actual link. Please note I'm not trying to advertise ;) here it is "www.leadstreet.rocks "

Comment: Ok see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have issued the same problem with some of my projects.

In fact, when I used `Application.OpenURL` with addresses like `www.google.com` it worked out of the box with computers but not with smartphone devices.

After hours of hair pulling, I just add the HTTP request protocol to the URL and that was it.

To comply with both computers and smartphones devices use `Application.OpenURL("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: yep it works now. Will accept as soon as it lets me. Thanks a bunch this would have tormented me for some time.

Answer (score 0):

You might forgot to add the protocol with the URL. In the case of windows machine it will work without any issue but when we try the same thing in android mobile then we have to provide the protocol to say that it's a valid URL.

Try to use like this,

```
Application.OpenURL("http://<YOUR_ADRESS_HERE>");
```

Eg: `Application.OpenURL("http://www.google.com");`

If you are trying to open any document using `Application.OpenURL` then it won't work. Unity removed that support in latest versions. You can use `AndroidOpenUrl.OpenUrl(documentUrl, dataType)` for those cases.

You will get a demo and installation steps of the package from the following repository.

https://github.com/codemaker2015/Unity-Android-Files-Opener